# save sequence of images in a folder using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to save images into a folder. I tried a code given below

```
      [Ilabel num] = bwlabel(If);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 83]);
 figure,imshow(Ibox);

 for n=1:num
        [r,c] = find(Ilabel==n);
        % Extract letter
        n1=Iout(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c));  
        % Resize letter (same size of template)
        img_r=imresize(n1,[42 24]);
        %figure,imshow(n1);
        %Uncomment line below to see letters one by one
         %imshow(img_r);pause(0.5)
 imwrite(img_r,['H:\\mainproject\\codes\\images\\test0.jpg' ]);
 end
```

But only the last letter is saved in the folder. I dont know where it made mistakes.I tried a lot but i didn't get it.please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be overwriting the images, since you are using the same name `test0.jpg`. Try:

```
[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(If);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 83]);
figure,imshow(Ibox);

 for n=1:num
        [r,c] = find(Ilabel==n);
        % Extract letter
        n1=Iout(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c));  
        % Resize letter (same size of template)
        img_r=imresize(n1,[42 24]);
        %figure,imshow(n1);
        %Uncomment line below to see letters one by one
        %imshow(img_r);pause(0.5)
        image_name = strcat('H:\\mainproject\\codes\\images\\test', num2str(n), '.jpg');
        imwrite(img_r,[image_name]);
 end
```

I actually can't test now, and couldn't just comment (points below 50). Hope it helps,